# What does 拉丝为加丝 mean?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

Could someone tell me what 拉丝为加丝 means? I searched it up on baidu and the first thing that came up was Las Vegas and it also makes sense within the context, but the characters are different from Las Vegas (拉斯维加斯), so I'm wondering if this means Las Vegas in a different dialect or if it means something else.

Context: “刚去了一趟国外那啥拉丝为加丝，在那里度假搞阳光浴，晒黑的，黑的有型吗？”

Understanding: I went abroad to a foreign place called Las Vegas where I had vacation, on vacation, I sunbathed, tanned, and blackened. Is it good-looking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean 拉斯维加斯， the transliteration of Las Vegas (Spanish for "The fields), a city in Nevada, famous for gambling and quick marriages!

Comment: Thank you very much for verifying my conjecture!

Comment: "...famous for gambling and quick marriages!", correct, but not for "搞阳光浴" :)

Comment: I was wrong: marriage is also a gamble, so actually only famous for gambling!!

Answer (score 1):

It indeed means 拉斯维加斯, but in an intended joking tone. And don't ever forget the existence of **那啥** (that whatsoever). Together with the funny transliteration, they imply that "I" am not boasting about this vacation and "I" am not obsessed with Las Vegas (See, I don't even care whatever that place is called).

The sentence could be understood as: I just went abroad to that whatever place called Las Wiejas and got tanned there because of sunbathing. Do I look good with a tan?

Las Wiejas is, of course, not the right name. But it is intended to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong characters. Should be 拉斯维加斯